# Qt errors while building app

Tags: android, c++, qt, c++11, build

When I **attempt** to build my project for android, these errors occurs:

```
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl
```

These are not just nonsignificant warnings! These are really important problems because Qt creator can't import Qt quick.
Thus, my application won't have any visual object.
How can I solve this error?
Also this is .pro file of my project:

```
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    downloader.cpp \
    filemanager.cpp
HEADERS += \
    downloader.h \
    filemanager.h
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
QT += network
QT += xml
QT += gui
QML_IMPORT_PATH = /home/muhammad/Qt5.9.0/5.9/android_armv7/qml/
#QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
DISTFILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    android/gradlew \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/build.gradle \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    android/gradlew.bat \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar \
    android/gradlew \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/build.gradle \
    android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties \
    android/gradlew.bat
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
```

Comment: Do the warnings come from the build tools, or from Qt Creator itself? If it's the latter, they are inconsequential.

Comment: @KubaOber i don't know! :(

Comment: "These are not just nonsignificant warnings! These are really important problems because Qt creator can't import Qt quick. Thus, my application won't have any visual object"

I have the same warnings but my qtquick objects correctly show up so I think that you can safely ignore them.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier but they don't show up for me. just a white screen shows up.

Comment: Where exactly do the warnings show up? Give us a screenshot.